# Почему keras не принимает данные?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras

Есть массив NumPy с 300 изображениями, каждое изображение представляет собой одномерный массив из 3145728 элементов, и при попытке обучить модель на этих данных:

```
model.fit(data, features, batch_size=64, epochs=3)
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (300, 1)

Как мне переделать массив данных, чтобы keras его принял?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по названию слоя: `conv2d_input` - это слой двумерной свертки [Conv2D](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/), который ожидает на вход 4х-мерный тензор с размерностями:

> 4+D tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (channels, rows, cols)` if
> `data_format='channels_first'`

или

> 4+D tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (rows, cols, channels)` if
> `data_format='channels_last'`

Поэтому либо вы будете подавать на вход тензор правильной размерности, либо вам придется изменить архитектуру НС (Нейронной Сети) таким образом, чтобы она могла работать с картинками "выпрямленными" в вектора.

Comment: Изображения приведены к одномерному массиву numpy.flatten по аналогии с задачами классификации, по-крайней мере я в таком виде подавал изображения на svm-классификатор, мне стоит опустить numpy.flatten в задачах свертки?

Comment: И какая архитектура CNN, на Ваш взгляд, лучше: архитектура, принимающая на вход одномерные массивы, или же принимающая на вход трехмерные данные?

Comment: Мой вопрос вы, можно сказать, решили, так как действительно указали на правильную ошибку, но возникла следующая проблема
Теперь сами тренировочные данные, имеющие 300 цветных изображений, принимаются, а вот выходные данные, имеющие 300 массивов с 70 точками, заданными двумя координатами-нет, дело из-за другой размерности выходного слоя:
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_12 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (300, 70, 2)

Comment: Погуглив, нашел следующий способ: после свертки, когда уже начинается голое машинная тренировка, приводить данные к размерности выходных, но мне кажется, что это бред и есть способы лучше
Может быть можно как-то отдельно задать размер выходных данных?